# How to fix IndentationError breaking out of If Else?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am trying to break out of on an `else` condition using `break` but it is giving me `IndentationError`:

```py
import json
import difflib
from difflib import get_close_matches

data=json.load(open("data.json"))

def translate(word):
    word=word.lower()
    if word in data:
        return data[word]
    elif len(get_close_matches(word,data.keys()))>0:
        yn= input("Did you mean %s instead. Type Y if you want to look up %s or Type any other key if you want to leave" % get_close_matches(word,data.keys())[0])
        if yn=="Y":
            return get_close_matches(word,data.keys())[0]
        else:
    break

    else:
        return ("This word does not  exist in the data, please check the word again")

user_word=input("Please enter your word:\n")

print(translate(user_word ))
```

Comment: Indent so it's under the `else:` to the right, not to the left of it?

Comment: But.... there is no loop to break out from...

Answer (score 0):

Python expects the first line of code to be indented one additional tab for every loop or conditional statement (basically anything ending in ':')

So indent break twice to solve that. However you likely don't actually want to break here, you probably want to return.

here is indenting break

```
import json
import difflib
from difflib import get_close_matches

data=json.load(open("data.json"))

def translate(word):
    word=word.lower()
    if word in data:
        return data[word]
    elif len(get_close_matches(word,data.keys()))>0:
        yn= input("Did you mean %s instead. Type Y if you want to look up %s or Type any other key if you want to leave" % get_close_matches(word,data.keys())[0])
        if yn=="Y":
            return get_close_matches(word,data.keys())[0]
        else:
            break

    else:
        return ("This word does not  exist in the data, please check the word again")

user_word=input("Please enter your word:\n")

print(translate(user_word ))
```

but you probably want

```
import json
import difflib
from difflib import get_close_matches

data=json.load(open("data.json"))

def translate(word):
    word=word.lower()
    if word in data:
        return data[word]
    elif len(get_close_matches(word,data.keys()))>0:
        yn= input("Did you mean %s instead. Type Y if you want to look up %s or Type any other key if you want to leave" % get_close_matches(word,data.keys())[0])
        if yn=="Y":
            return get_close_matches(word,data.keys())[0]
        else:
            return # or return ""

    else:
        return ("This word does not  exist in the data, please check the word again")

user_word=input("Please enter your word:\n")

print(translate(user_word ))
```

edit for additional info: in python break is used to exit a loop early as done in [these examples](https://www.programiz.com/python-programming/break-continue) If you attempt to break when you are not inside a loop you will get a `SyntaxError: 'break' outside loop`

Comment: *I have never seen anyone 'break' out of a method* - because it is not possible. You `return` or `yield` from a function, not `break`

Comment: yeah i was just adding that to my answer when you commented